# getType() in opennlp.tools.util.Span class?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I am using opennlp `opennlp.tools.chunker.ChunkerME` implementation for finding chunks. In this class i am calling `chunkAsSpans(..)` method which returns `Span[]`.

So, this `Span` instance has `getType()` getter method which is returning types like 
**NP, VP** etc.

Here i am wondering what type means for Span? Is it the POS?

Comment: `NP` - noun phrase, `VP` - verb phrase.

Comment: Ok, i had the same feeling, searched over web but didnt got any documentation saying this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NP` stands for a noun phrase, and `VP` stands for a verb phrase.

If you have a look at  the [*Chunker Training*](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html) help page, you will see the following:

> The training data must be converted to the OpenNLP chunker training format, that is based on [CoNLL2000](http://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2000/chunking/): The train data consist of three columns separated by spaces. Each word has been put on a separate line and there is an empty line after each sentence. The first column contains the current word, the second its part-of-speech tag and the third its chunk tag. The chunk tags contain the name of the chunk type, for example I-**NP for noun phrase words** and I-**VP for verb phrase words**.